# Need to bind two dataset to a tablix. Please find image in description, how to achieve this kind of structure in SSRS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, dataset, grouping

I am using vs 2008. I want below structure in my rdl. Rdl having two dataset.

1. one for main tablix to display name, email id, mobile, address
2. second for medical issues

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lucle.png)

Comment: The title says 1 dataset but your question says 2 datasets. Which is it?

Comment: I need to bind two datasets to a tablix but as per tablix property we can bind only one dataset at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only bind a tablix to one dataset. The only way you can do this is to either

1. combine the data in your dataset query or, if that is not possible
2. use the `LOOKUP()` function to get the required data from your second dataset

You can read more about `LOOKUP()` here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to have the Medical Issues as a Subreport in your main table of employees.

Create a new report with just the Medical issues part of the table. You can copy the existing report and remove the main elements. Add a parameter for the Employee ID and filter the dataset by it.

The unneeded datasets can be removed - the main report doesn't need the Medical Issues and the Medical Issues doesn't need the Employee dataset.

In the main report, where you have your Medical Issues, insert a subreport. Select the Medical Issues report you created and link it by employee ID.

For more details, see MS Docs: [add a subreport and parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-subreport-and-parameters-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)